# How do I upload files from a phone to my Amazon S3 server?

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I'm developing a mobile app with Unity and using S3 to store and retrieve assets, I can download asset bundles just fine from the server to the phone, but how do I upload files from the phone to the server?

I used the PostObject function from the AWS Unity SDK, and it works fine if I upload from the computer as I know the directory, but I'm not sure how to get the phone's photo gallery to upload to the s3 server.

This is the PostObject function

```c#
public void PostObject(string fileName)
{     
    ResultText.text = "Retrieving the file";
    var stream = new FileStream("file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileName,
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    Debug.Log("kek");
    ResultText.text += "\nCreating request object";
    var request = new PostObjectRequest()
    {
        Bucket = S3BucketName,
        Key = fileName,
        InputStream = stream,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private,
        Region = _S3Region
    };

    ResultText.text += "\nMaking HTTP post call";

    Client.PostObjectAsync(request, (responseObj) =>
    {
        if (responseObj.Exception == null)
        {
            ResultText.text += string.Format("\nobject {0} posted to bucket {1}",
            responseObj.Request.Key, responseObj.Request.Bucket);
        }
        else
        {
            ResultText.text += "\nException while posting the result object";
            ResultText.text += string.Format("\n receieved error {0}",
            responseObj.Response.HttpStatusCode.ToString());
        }
    });
}
```

And this is where I'm using it to upload the picture taken from the phone to the server

```c#
public void TakePicture(int maxSize)
{
    NativeCamera.Permission permission = NativeCamera.TakePicture((path) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
        if (path != null)
        {
            // Create a Texture2D from the captured image
            Texture2D imageTexture = NativeCamera.LoadImageAtPath(path, maxSize);
            if (imageTexture == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                return;
            }

            //picturePreview.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            //picturePreview.texture = imageTexture;

            Texture2D readableTexture = DuplicateTexture(imageTexture);

            StartCoroutine(AddImageJob(readableTexture));
            //Saves taken photo to the Image Gallery
            if (isSaveFiles)
            {
                NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(imageTexture, "AReview", "test");

                //Upload to Amazon S3
                aws.PostObject(imageTexture.name);
                aws.PostObject("test");
            }
        }
    }, maxSize);

    Debug.Log("Permission result: " + permission);
}
```

Any clues?

Thank you.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: Does the fileStream work on the phone? Two possible issues here: On Android you can't simply access the [`streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) since it is compressed so you have to go via a `UnityWebRequest` (read linked API). Second you should never use `+ "/"` direct string concatenation for system paths. Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically uses the correct path separator depending on the OS.

Comment: @derHugo the filestream doesn't work on the phone, I'm just not sure how to access the android gallery.

I'm trying to make a function where after I take a photo, it is uploaded to the cloud